# what parts are stored in the CPU cache (cache design and replacement algorithms)

Tags: c, algorithm, caching, operating-system

I am currently learning about operating systems, and I am having trouble with one problem about CPU cache that recently came up.

The problem:

Assuming we have a 1 CPU system only running one process that basically runs in a forever loop like this:

```c
typedef char[64] TBLOCK;
TBLOCK memory[20000];

int main(void) {
  int sum = 0;
  while(1) {
    for(int i=0; i<0x4000; ++i) {
      sum += memory[i][0];
    }
  }
}
```

And assuming that the system has a 1MiB cache where each line holds 64 bytes.

What parts of the code are stored in cache and how would you calculate the hit-rate for the different paging algorithms FIFO, LRU and Random. Which algorithm would be best suited for the problem?

My initial thought was that we have a cache with 16384 lines. The for loop iterates up to this same number, 16384. If the only data that is stored in the cache is the `memory[i][0]` variable, then the entirety of the needed memory variable is constantly stored in cache, no matter if we use FIFO or LRU, but not for random. Resulting in a 100% hit-rate for these two algorithms. Also, the actual cache structure would be the same with LRU and FIFO, as we keep iterating in the same direction. With the LRU the element least used will be erased which should turn out to be the end of the list same as the FIFO.

But as I said, I am not sure if this is the right approach and if the `sum` variable and the new sum calculated are stored in cache as well. This would certainly change the entirety of the cache allocation process.

Comment: There is something missing here.... The number of cache ways! Without it, stuff like LRU makes no sense.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question for C, since the compiler has choices about what it does. In this case, gcc removes all memory accesses since the `sum` variable is never used: https://godbolt.org/z/68sYKTd9E

Comment: If `sum` were used, and `memory` filled with random bytes so the compiler can't be clever, I'd expect `sum` to be kept in a register, so would not interfere with the cache.

Comment: I have a feeling that you have misunderstood the question. Talking about "paging algoritms" makes little sense in this context.

Comment: Anyway... with the information given, the answer is that all of the accessed `memory` can be held in cache. In other words - once it has been read into cache no further cache miss will happen. This assumes that `sum` and `i` is register-only variables

Comment: "What parts of the code are stored in cache ..." This is also kind of unclear. The question seems to refer to data cache but code would go to instruction cache.